# Question about creating table, relation and cardinality

Tags: sql, database, relational-database, cardinality

I have a problem creating a database (I am still learning). I need to create a database for a company that generates a report like the one in the image.

[Report to reply](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ODqfp.png)

I have the tables created as follows, but I have a problem in the t_stack with the t_tracking_number.

[DB model and Relationship](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j0GTb.png)

The part that I don´t know how to do, is create the t_stack table, to register an id_stack, an id_driver, and then insert many tracking_numbers. at this moment according to the image, I should register  for every track_number, an id_stack and an id_driver.

If someone can give me an idea of ​​how to do it, or if I must  change whatever in the database it doesn't matter. Sorry if I didn't make myself clear, this is my first project and I want to do my best. 
Thank you.

Comment: What conceptual object does `t_stack` represent? Aside: I seed no point prefixing every table with `t_`, standard practice is to use `TitleCase` in singular form without a prefix

Comment: Oh. ok, i'll change the  name for the tables, ty for the advice..
with the Stack I want create a Collection of Track_numbers  and give it an id to that collection,  and a driver.

Comment: But what relation do Shipment and Stack have to each other? They sound the same thing. Either way you have repeated `driver_id` between them, there should only be one, as one is functionally dependent on the other, I would imagine

Comment: IDK if i'm doing good xD.. but im trying to do is: on Shipment  make a resume of everithing, i mean, make a header with  the driver, date, Manifest(this one will be filled  by the government), an id for that Shipment, and below of that header, the group of all tracking numbers.   and thanks for the answer.

Comment: So remove `t_stack` you just need driver, shipment, tracking_number. Incidentally, knowing the industry a little, I think it would normally be manifest instead of shipment and shipment instead of tracking_number

Comment: Thanks.. i thought the same about deleting t_stack... But idk how to make the report with that data... I mean.. many tracking numbers and to that "group" give it an id_number.

Comment: Isn't a shipment a group of tracking numbers though?

Comment: Yeahp.. i thought that should make another table for that and then vinculate it.... ¿ So.. Could I insert the tracking numbers  on the report, having a single ID, and deleting the stack table?

Answer (score 0):

You have to add in your **t_stack** table an id (**ID_stack**), identity increment as a PrimaryKey. Then you can have all **tracking_numbers** and combinations you need.

Comment: But, if i do that, i should insert an ID_stack  with every tracking number XD